# LUIS Programmatic SDK functions stopped working after Microsoft Build 2019

Tags: c#, azure, azure-language-understanding

In the past, I've built a simple console application that uses the LUIS Programmatic SDK to create / manage LUIS services and it worked just fine. Recently, I executed this application and some of the specific SDK functions - such as ImportApp and ExportApp - stopped working. 
This happenend around the same time Microsoft announced the new "LUIS V3" stuff (Build 2019).
Is there any change I need to do in order to have my application up and running again or are they doing some kind of maintenance and I need to wait until it's completed ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Some functions. These are the functions I call when I want to create an App and import it to LUIS.

```
public async Task<string> CreateApp(string culture, string name, string description = "")
    {
        //Culture validation
        IList<AvailableCulture> availableCultures = await Client.Apps.ListSupportedCulturesAsync();
        AvailableCulture usageCulture = availableCultures.Where(c => c.Code.ToLower() == culture.ToLower()).First();

        if (usageCulture == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Culture not supported");
        }

        AppCulture = usageCulture.Code;

        //Luis App Creation

        App = new LuisApp();
        App.Name = name;
        App.Culture = usageCulture.Code;
        App.Desc = description;
        App.VersionId = "0.1";
        //--
        App.ClosedLists = new List<ClosedList>();
        App.Composites = new List<HierarchicalModel>();
        App.Entities = new List<HierarchicalModel>();
        App.Intents = new List<HierarchicalModel>();
        App.ModelFeatures = new List<JSONModelFeature>();
        App.PatternAnyEntities = new List<PatternAny>();
        App.Patterns = new List<PatternRule>();
        App.PrebuiltEntities = new List<PrebuiltEntity>();
        App.RegexEntities = new List<RegexEntity>();
        App.RegexFeatures = new List<JSONRegexFeature>();
        App.Utterances = new List<JSONUtterance>();
        //--

        return App.Name;
    }

public async Task<Guid> ImportApp()
    {
        try
        {
            if (AppGuid == Guid.Empty)
            {
                AppGuid = await Client.Apps.ImportAsync(App);
            }
            else
            {

                double version = double.Parse(App.VersionId, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
                version = version + 0.1;
                App.VersionId = version.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
                //--
                //App.VersionId = "0.2";

                await Client.Versions.ImportAsync(AppGuid, App);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return AppGuid;
    }
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: Added the 2 starting functions of my application. When Importing, it returns an empty guid but the app is imported to LUIS portal

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was not related to the code in question. Thanks to the ones who read this